# how flink handles early event? ignore or create separate window?

Tags: apache-flink

The watermark and late event handling is easy to understand, but how about early event? For example, if the original stream contains events happened from 3:00 to 4:00, but if I insert some events which happened from 6:00 to 7:00 into the stream, then how flink handles them? It would create separate window(s) for them and when the window expires, they get handled too?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the watermarking strategy, early events can advance the watermark and then cause subsequent "on time" events to be considered late.

Answer (score 3):

Early events are not dropped but put into the corresponding window. The window is processed when the watermark passes the end timestamp of the window. So, Flink is able to maintain several windows at the same time.

Comment: So would I need to implement the custom Watermarking logic so that early events don't advance the watermark? Is there something built-in I can use?

Comment: Yes, depending on the strategy of the watermark assigner, early events advance watermarks. You could implement a more conservative watermark assigner, e.g., one that computes watermark on the median of the 9 highest timestamps. There is no built-in assigner for this, but it should be fairly easy to implement.